# Can cherry-picking from a branch cause trouble rebasing this branch to master

Tags: git, merge, rebase, cherry-pick

**Context**: I have an experimental branch `crazy-idea` where I did some wild things in a dedicated sub-dir `madness/{src,docs}`. A ton of commits, with notes, pictures, hacky scripts to create plots.  Now that I have fully understood what I'm doing it's time to edit the actual source files in `src/` by adding new functions and alter existing ones.

Since the mess in `crazy-idea` would clutter the history of master, a new branch `good-idea` was created to merge the changes in `src/` into master.  Convince suggests that I alter the files in `src/` still being in `crazy-idea` and then cherry-pick the commits from within `good-idea`.

**Now my question**: Given that `good-idea` was merged into master and some commits were done in master after this event.  When I go back to `crazy-idea` to further iron out some other aspect of my idea, is there trouble to be expected in `src/` while rebasing to master?

The alternative is to leave `src/` within `crazy-idea` alone, make a copy of the sub-dir and look at my notes this way while coding directly in `good-idea`.

What do you guys suggest is smarter?

**EDIT** Well, as expected I got conflicts during

```
git rebase master
```

in `crazy-idea`.  In future I will introduce changes only in exactly one branch and use cherry-picking only when I know that it's more or less abandoned.

**EDIT** I solved my situation as follows:
There have been N commits with changes in `src/`.  Lets say the last non `src/` changing commit had the message 'foobar'.  After the rebase failed:

```
$ git rebase --abort
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
HEAD is now at ...
# more hard resets, I think actually N
HEAD is now at ... foobar
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying ..
...
```

Done.  This evidently isn't as straight forward as I hoped, but not too bad either.  I think I will go this route instead of copying `madness/`.

Answer (score 2):

Git should not have very much trouble reconciling the cherry-picks.  When rebasing, Git will ignore any commits (and even hunks within a commit's diff) that introduce change that has already been introduced on the target branch.

Comment: Nice.  My guess/hope was that git ignores where to commit comes from and just looks at the content when rebasing.  Btw, have you actually used git the way I described or are you just confident that it will cope fine.

Comment: I have done some pretty complicated rebases and I've seen it correctly drop whole commits that had already been integrated.

Comment: Sounds awesome.  I will go ahead and mark your answer in a day or two if it worked out :P  Thanks!

Comment: Odd.  For really complex branching/patching patterns it can have a bit of trouble reconciling things and you'll just have to fix the merge conflicts.